# Present journal paper at conference or the same work at multiple conferences

Tags: publications, research-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Under what circumstances can one republish a conference paper/presentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/under-what-circumstances-can-one-republish-a-conference-paper-presentation)

I have recently completed a Masters of Science which I pursued to fill a personal goal and to advance our development of a regional tsunami warning system.

Having read the thread on multiple publishing and presenting I am still confused as this is a new issue for me. Coming from Government we present on special projects or findings any number of times.

If I wish to publish my findings in an academic journal am I precluded from presenting at any conferences?

If I present at a localised scientific conference without published proceedings, am I precluded from presenting at a global one?

Can I focus one on localised context and the other on the global implications, then cite having presented at the local level?

Comment: There are a number of very similar questions, perhaps duplicates. See the links in [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5822/1033) below.

Answer (score 4):

The exact answer depends on the topic, but normally:

- Publishing finding in an academic journal does not preclude presenting at conferences (*[except in computer science!](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/present-journal-paper-at-conference-or-the-same-work-at-multiple-conferences/5822#comment10456_5822)*). In fact, it's quite common to first publish a paper in a peer-reviewed journal, then go to one or even several conferences to advertise it. Just be sure to mention it at the conference, because if there are proceedings, there may exist conferences with different ideas, depending on the field.
- Presenting at a local conference does not preclude presenting at a global one, certainly not if the local conference has no proceedings, because then there is not really any publication at all.
- The answer to your third question is most likely *yes*.

To be 100% sure, contact the organisers of the conferences.

See also:

- [Publishing the same results at multiple conferences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5314/1033)
- [Submitting the same research to multiple conferences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/51/1033)
- [Journal publication and acceptance to competitive conferences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/331/1033)
- [Under what circumstances can one republish a conference paper/presentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2673/1033)

Comment: Dear gerrit and aeismail; Thank you so very much for your quick and informative responses and the additional links. Once I get over the first time gitters it will be ok but I appreciate folks like you who are willing the mentor. All the best and happy holidays - Lis

Comment: _Publishing finding in an academic journal does not preclude presenting at conferences_ — Except in computer science.

Answer (score 4):

In fields outside of computer science, publishing a paper does not normally prevent you from presenting your work at a conference; as gerrit points out, the two go hand in hand quite frequently, and many people will speak about just-published research in a presentation. (I know I have!)

However, what publishing a paper *can* do is change the *form* of the presentation, int he sense that the journal may place some restrictions on how you can reuse the material that has been published.

For instance, you may need to provide citations when including figures from the paper in your presentation, as well as citing any text that is taken directly from what has been published. For many journals, however, you may do so without asking prior permission, so long as you include the appropriate citations.

Comment: _Publishing a paper does not normally prevent you from presenting your work at a conference_ — Except in computer science.

Comment: @JeffE: Why does CS seem to work so differently from every other major field of academia?

Comment: You have to start with the understanding that conference proceedings are the primary publication venue in CS, and work backwards from there.  Presenting at a conference is simply a perk of publishing a paper in a conference proceedings.  But if you've already published a paper elsewhere, you can't publish it again in a conference proceedings — no double dipping! — so you can't present it at a conference either.

Comment: @JeffE: That I knew. What I don't understand is why only CS seems to have this model. What are the differences in CS's evolution compared to other academic fields that would lead to this radical paradigm change?

Comment: The standard fiction is that even in the 70s and 80s, the field moved too fast for journal papers (which typically had a several-months-long review cycle) to be useful.  In some subfields, a six-month old paper may as well not exist.  Computer scientists were relatively rich, flights were relatively cheap, and there was no internet, so conference proceedings filled that gap.  [Other fields have responded to the same pressure by imposing fast review cycles and page limits on their journal papers, but CS has (largely) resisted the urge to abridge our archival publications.]

Comment: Also, computer science grew out of a mixture of mathematics and electrical engineering (with occasional bits of physics), which gave us a healthy(?) disrespect for the scholarly traditions of other fields (and our own). _So what_ if everybody else does it differently?

Comment: Well, for one thing, it can make it a lot harder to evaluate personnel for an interdisciplinary position. One candidate comes in with 5 or 6 high-quality journal publications. The other comes in with a bunch of conference proceedings (which could also be very high-quality). Guess which one the non-CS people on the panel would likely prefer?

Comment: The one with the more convincing recommendation letters, of course.  (Ha ha only serious.)

Comment: Here in Germany, the letters of recommendation come _after_ the finalists are selected.

Comment: A question please: what if the journal and conference were submitted at the same time ? We had this issue before. We could not cite any of them because none of them were published (even at the phase of revised journal and camera-ready conference). This issue raised a lot of opinions. What is your opinion please ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but outside of CS, it's OK to present a work at a conference while the journal paper is under consideration. Citations are tricky, because, as you said, there's nothing formally published to cite; however, in the conference presentation, you can always "cite" the paper as "submitted to _Journal X._"

Comment: @JeffE, for me the weird part is to understand which authority dictate this rule in computer science? I posted a full question http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61547/which-authority-dictates-regulates-that-in-computer-science-a-journal-paper-cann